# WPF TextBox automatically scrolls cursor into view when focused

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, wpf-controls, scroll

I'm making a simple log viewer which is composed of a big `TextBox` which shows the file, and a `DispatchTimer` that updates the `TextBox` from time to time by setting its `Text` property.

Whenever the focus is set to the `TextBox`, it keeps automatically scrolling to the place where the cursor is, even when I'm explicitly issue `ScrollToEnd()` on it. (In that case, the UI shows the scrollbar "jumping" from the end back to the cursor position).

How can I cause the `TextBox` to keep its current scrolled position and ignore the position of the cursor?

Comment: One question. Why you not use a RichTextBox?

Comment: Lots of content, I'm afraid RichTextBox will be too slow and too complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Scrolling it is better to use a [ScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.aspx)

```
 <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="80">
   <TextBlock Name="debugLog" />
 </ScrollViewer>
```

Assuming the Log is not editable.

Comment: But then, how would I scroll to a specific line? (It is not editable indeed).

Comment: can I scroll to a specific line with `ScrollViewer`? Please edit your answer so that I'll be able to accept it.